# It is possible to take text-wrap property in dropdowncheckboxes in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my web application, i need to display selected text in section box if i checked many names i need to display the text in another line in anyone tell me is it possible to do or not. i need to show all the selected items in selection box.

I am getting result like [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQrM6.png). But i need to display all the checked items in selection box.How can i do this.

.aspx:

```
    <asp:DropDownCheckBoxes ID="dropdown1" runat="server" AddJQueryReference="true" UseSelectAllNode="true" UseButtons="true"  
OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropdown1_SelectedIndexChanged"
     AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="drpdwnstyle" Width="700px" >              
                        </asp:DropDownCheckBoxes>


  <style type="text/css">
     .drpdwnstyle {
            width: 250px;        
            position:absolute;              
            text-align: left;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            direction: ltr;                      
        }</style>
```

.CS:

```
  protected void dropdown1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            List<String> checkedList = new List<string>();
            foreach (ListItem item in dropdown1.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {
                    checkedList.Add(item.Value);
                }
            }
            dropdown1.Texts.SelectBoxCaption = String.Join(",", checkedList.ToArray());
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Remove **text-overflow: ellipsis;**
 Add **white-space: initial;**

```
style type="text/css">
     .drpdwnstyle {
            width: 250px;        
            position:absolute;              
            text-align: left;
            white-space: initial;
            direction: ltr;                      
        }
```